# samba linux access log file location

Tags: linux, samba, logging

experts!

I have a linux smb installation, and, as well as apache logs every access (what ip, when, requests what resource), I wonder if smb does the same:

I'd like to have a log file that reflects whenever, whoever, is trying to pull what out of my server.

Does linux smb store this valuable information? If it does, where?

Thank u so much!

Comment: [ubuntu - Samba logging all to get logs about all user activities on shared folders and files - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/484442/samba-logging-all-to-get-logs-about-all-user-activities-on-shared-folders-and-fi/484474)

Comment: Thanks! I followed the indications and set the log level to top (10), but even so, it logs A LOT of metainfo, but no log of who-downloads-what-when